# Having some weird behaviour with jQuery $(window).scrollTop(); on mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scrolltop

I'm trying to fade in the header of my page when scrolling to a certain point.

On mobile for some reason when scrolling, it doesn't fade in at the specific point. What happens is, that it doesn't appear until you have fully stopped scrolling and it appears without the fade animation.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
//Header to appear on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 150) {
        $('.header-bar-small').fadeIn(); 
    } else {
        $('.header-bar-small').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: try using offset().top instead

Comment: @Ron.Basco thanks for that. Unfortunately didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into the problem with Dennis (disclaimer: we work together so I had the advantage of viewing the source code), we discovered a solution.

There were three elements on the page that were supposed to appear: one was appearing on scroll, while the others were not appearing until the scroll had stopped.  We determined that the `scrollTop` position was being updated and was correct, and that the javascript that makes the elements appear was executing correctly.  We even removed the `fadeIn` (replaced with a `show`) to make sure it wasn't a deferred rendering issue.

It turned out to be a CSS issue.  For some reason, we were able to fix it by wrapping the target div in another div with only `position:fixed` and `z-index:1`.  The odd thing is that the element we were trying to show already had these styles, but for whatever reason, adding the wrapper fixes it.

For example:

```
<div class="showHideWrapper" style="position:fixed; z-index:1;">
    <div class="header-bar-small" style="position:fixed; z-index:1;">
        This should work.
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Header to appear on scroll
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 150) {
                $('.showHideWrapper').fadeIn(); 
            } else {
                $('.showHideWrapper').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

We tried stripping out the styles on that element, or applying the same behaviour to an entirely new element, but it didn't work until we did the above.  Setting `position:relative` or `position:absolute` didn't do the job, probably because the child element was fixed also.

For now, doing something like this may help those with a similar issue, but if anyone is able to provide a definitive explanation on what causes this, I'm all ears.